# Representation of the Heisenberg group.

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, heisenberg-group

I am understanding the Heisenberg group interpreted as a group of operators. At the moment, I have been able to understand the following:

The set of matrices
\begin{align}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
is the Heisenberg group ($H$). If $\mathrm{e}$ is the exponential (matrix), then $\mathrm{e}^{X}=A$ with $X=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & b\\ 0 & 0 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. The set of matrices $X$ is the Lie Algebra of the Lie Group $H$.If $\Pi$ is a representation, i.e., $\Pi:H\to \text{GL}(V)$ then, for each $A\in H$,

\begin{align}\Pi(A=\mathrm{e}^{X}):V\to V\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(\Pi(A)f)(x)=(\mathrm{e}^{\pi(X)}f)(x),\quad f\in V,\, 
\end{align}
with $\pi(X)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\Pi(\mathrm{e}^{tX})$

But, I understand that the Heisenberg group of operators is
$\Pi(A)=\mathrm{e}^{a\partial_x+bx+c}$, Given this, my questions arise:

**Question 1.** The representation is $\Pi(A)=\mathrm{e}^{a\partial_x+bx+c}$?

**Question 2** . What is the vector space $V$? Can $V$ be the space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

**Question 3**.The exponential is $\mathrm{e}^{a\partial_x+bx+c}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a\partial_x+bx+c)^k}{k!}$?converges? in what sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

The Lie algebra of the Heisenberg group is generated by the trace--free and nilpotent matrices
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad 
Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad 
Z=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
which satisfy
$$
XY=Z\,,\quad YX=XZ=ZX=YZ=ZY=0
$$
and therefore the commutation relations
\begin{align}
[X,Y]=Z\,,\quad [X,Z]=0\,,\quad [Y,Z]=0\,.
\end{align}
Three vector fields (operators) that satisfy the same relations and therefore generate
the same Lie algebra are
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{X}&=\partial_x\,, &\boldsymbol{Y}&=x\,\partial_z+\partial_y\,,&\boldsymbol{Z}&=\partial_z\,. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, though, my question focuses more on: what is $V$ space? Is the exponential the one given by a power series or exponential map? They are coincides?

Comment: These are not the only operators one could work with. Another important representation is the [Schrödinger representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Representation_theory). This link tells you the function space and has the book of Hall as reference.

Comment: The fact that the exponential operator $e^{D}$ is convergent in $L^2(R)$ makes me upset. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Since I have never studied the Heisenberg group from that functional analytic angle I am afraid I won't be of much help. Best if you look closely at Hall and perhaps formulate a more detailed new MSE question to attract some expert's advice.